# react native element type is invalid : expected a string or a class/function but got undefined, check the render method of NavigatorNavigationBar

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
<Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'Home', index: 0 }}
        renderScene={ (route, navigator) => <Home ref="home" /> }
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
              routeMapper={{
                LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
                { return (<Text>Cancel</Text>); },
                RightButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
                { return (<Text>Done</Text>); },
                Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
                { return (<Text>Awesome Nav Bar</Text>); },
              }}
              style={{backgroundColor: 'gray'}}
          />
        }
    />
```

It throws an error says Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'NavigatorNavigationBar'.

Comment: Are you sure you imported both your Navigator and Text components at the top of your file?

Comment: This error usually happens with wrong imports. If you are using named imports (import {A, B} from 'c') check that the names are correct and that the value is not undefined (for instance, `console.log(A)`).

Comment: What does your `Home` component look like? It's possible that you're not exporting that properly as well.

Comment: Thanks @stinodes, the problem is solved. The reason is the wrong imports....Don't know why the error information doesn't say anything relate to the wrong imports.

Comment: Well, it can't know it's because of your imports. It just checks for whatever variable you referenced in your scope. If it's not there, it'll be `undefined`, which is indeed not a string, class nor function. Hence the error.